# Shopify custom variants | price not update

Tags: ajax, shopify, liquid

I have created 3 default shopify variants and two custom variants, I have implement price updation login when variant change price update on price section but when I add the product add to cart at that time only product variant price updated

Suppose: default variant price is : $45 after custom variant option selected price is $90 when i add this product to cart product add with price $45 not $90, I want that product add with updated price $90.

Suppose: default variant price is : $45 after custom variant option selected price is $90 when i add this product to cart product add with price $45 not $90, I want that product add with updated price $90.

Comment: You can't update a price from frontend with JS and liquid in Shopify.

Comment: you need to use different logic or 3rd party like advance product option for this purpose.

Comment: I am not looking for a third-party app, I want a custom solution. could you please elaborate on what kind of custom logic I need to develop

Comment: You need to create extra options with price and hide them from the frontend, add those options when someone chooses extra during the custom option.

Comment: Shopify only permits us max 3 options. How can I make other and hide?

Comment: I think need to read more about custom how liquid code and api works to sort it out

Comment: I have already created options, price is also updated on the product page, but when I add a product to the cart the variant price is added to the cart and not updated because I have created a custom option (static) and the product added to the cart does not have variant created with custom options. I just want how to update the price on a cart with the existing product variant ID. if you can provide me with contact details it will be easier to connect and understand issue for you

Comment: Shopify does not work like woocommerce, with API you can't update from frontend, you need to use 3rd party app or develop your own custom app.